# How can I access request data in a template

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

I'm using bottle for a toy application. It's my first time getting with the framework.

I'm curious about how to access some keys I've added to the request object from inside a template.

Doing a naive `{{request.key}}` raises an exception saying that `request`is not defined, so I'm gessing that the object is not passed to every template context..

It is information that I'll be accessing in every view so I think this is the right approach, but I'm not nailing bottle's way of doing it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add the request to the template render function

```
return template('hello_template', name=name, request=request)
```

The render template function passes keyword arguments as local variables inside the template.  Nothing is passed to the template context for you.